# Powershell : open ie without generating temporary files

Tags: powershell

I wrote a scrip in Powershell to open ie and get webpage content automatically every minute to check if my API for website is working correctly:

```
$ie = New-Object -com internetexplorer.application
$ie.navigate($url)
...
$ie.Quit()
```

After a month my disk C is strangely filled up with IE temporary files, nearly 20GB. I think maybe it's related to my script. The version is Internet Explorer 10.

So how can I open ie without generating these files ? Thanks.

Comment: I don't know if that is an option as the computer has to download content in order to render the website properly ... hence temp files. You could just [clear the IE cache](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Clear-Internet-Explorer-5ee32ff6) every time that is run but that could impact regular activities with IE. Also have you tested your theory? Should not be to hard to clear the cache and run your code several times to be sure about your assumption.

Comment: @Matt Thanks but I'm sure this is why the problem occurs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is better to say not how not to generate cache files at opening but how to clear them after this. As far as I see it now here you can try to clear those files by yourself as [here](http://www.rushis.com/2011/06/programatically-clearing-cache-history-cookies-data-in-ie-789/). Or you can set up IE to clear them by itself as per [here](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/2130/ie7_clear_browser_cache_exit/). Also [here some help](http://www.groovypost.com/howto/automatically-clear-ie7-ie8-ie9-browser-cache-history-temp-files-at-exit/).

Comment: Thanks very much for the link !